# A short question about the direct limits and direct sum of commutative rings.

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

By viewing a ring as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, it is possible to define the direct limit of rings following the same procedure for modules. Let's suppose to work with commutative rings with unity. It seems quite evident to me that the direct limit of rings is still a commutative ring, but could *not* have the neutral element respect to the multiplication. Am I missing something, or is it right? Furthermore, it is the same for an arbitrary direct sum of rings, isn't it?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers

Ps: roughly speaking, the reason that I see is that the multiplication in both cases is defined components by components, and because in a direct sum the number of non zero components is finite, "the element $(1,1,..1,...)$" cannot exists.

Comment: What has a direct limit to do with direct sums?

Comment: @Bernard I defined the direct limit as the direct sum of a directed set of modules quotient by submodule generated by a particular kind of elements.

Comment: My definfinition uses the disjoint union of the directed set of modules (considered as sets) modulo the  equivalence relation that $x_i\in M_i$ and $x_j\in M_j$ are equivalent if there exist $k\in I,\enspace k>i,j$ such that $f_{ik}(x_i)=f_{jk}(x_k)$.

Comment: @Bernard My definition (from the book of Atiyah-MacDonald) takes instead the direct sum of all the modules, and then makes the quotient by the module generated by the same equivalence relation you say :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a unit element because all units in the different $A_i$ (identified with their image in the direct sum) satisfy the equivalence relation. In other words, $(\dots, 0,1\,(i\text{-th place}), 0, \dots)$ is equivalent to $(\dots, 0,1\, (j\text{-th place}), 0, \dots)$, so that, multiplying the class of an element $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ by $1$ amounts to multiply each $x_i$ (which are non-zero for a finite number of them) by the relevant unit.

Comment: There is still an action of $\mathbb{Z}$ so that $1\cdot x = x$, but it's not true that there is actually an element in the direct sum that behaves as unity.

Comment: This element is not in the direct sum but in the quotient, and each time you take the right representative.

Comment: This is only true for certain directed systems, and in particular it's _not_ true for the direct sum.  If there is no map $R\to S$, there is no reason that $1_R$ would be identified with $1_S$.

Comment: One could augment a directed system to include the natural maps $\mathbb{Z}\to R$, but this isn't explicitly mentioned anywhere.

Comment: Anyway, the O..'s definition comes from an exercise in Atiyah-Macdonald, so we have to do with it. Personally, I use Bourbaki's canonical definition.

Comment: We're using the same definition.  You're making the assumption that the directed system is a connected graph.  The direct sum, for example, is a direct limit with no transition maps, and the equivalence relation is trivial.  Some definitions omit this case, but this should be explicit, not implicit.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that we can't form infinite direct sums in this way while remaining in the category of rings with unity.

However, the direct sum of rings is not supposed to be a direct limit in any case, because the (finite) coproduct is $\otimes$, not $\oplus$.  The category of rings is very different from the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, and we shouldn't use direct limits in one to compute direct limits in the other.